# Close MessageBox.Show() when its parent form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a parent form with child form that is automatically close when the app got idle for a certain amount of time. The child form has a button that when it is clicked, a MessageBox will be shown to make confirmation from the user of the app.

The issue I am having right now is that when the app is idle and the child form is open with its MessageBox is shown, the child form does not close and it freezes. The other thing is, I could not close the MessageBox as well by clicking the 'OK' button.

Do you have any idea how could I solve it?
Thanks.

I have tried googling but I couldn't find any resources.

Comment: how do you show the message box?

Comment: Hi @LeandroBardelli, thank you for responding. I'm calling it with MessageBox.Show().

Answer (score 0):

If you have a child window open, you should have a handle to it.
I have no issue having the child close with a dialog open using this code:

CHILD:

```
public partial class Child : Window
{
  public Child () => InitializeComponent ();

  private void openmsg_click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    => MessageBox.Show ( "ok", "dialog", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel );
}
```

MAIN:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private readonly Timer timer = new Timer ();
  private Child? child = null;

  public MainWindow () => InitializeComponent ();//

  private void Timer_Elapsed ( object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e )
    => Dispatcher.Invoke ( () =>
    {
      timer.Stop ();
      child?.Close ();
    } );

  private void openchild_click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
  {
    child = new Child ();
    child.Show ();

    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start ();
  }

  private void Window_Closing ( object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e )
  {
    timer.Stop ();
    child?.Close ();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg M, thank you for your effort. I will try this solution if it solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Greg M, i see that you are working with WPF, but im doing it with WinForms. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If I remember right, you would implement OnClosing of child form to clean up things instead of Window_Closing

Comment: Hi Greg M, yes, you're right. And the child form should also close the MessageBox if it is being shown. What would be the difference between FormClosing and FormClosed.

Comment: "...ing" events represent the 'request' to perform an action at which time you could abort that request.   "...ed" events represent that the action is actually being performed.

think of "...ing" as it asking you permission

Comment: Hi Greg M, thanks. I understand it now.  Hopefully I could find a solution to the issue i'm facing. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Greg M, I find this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7968/MessageBox-with-a-timeout-for-NET which I think solve my problem. Thanks.